# syd.dm_exec_requests: open_transaction_count - What does it mean?

Tags: sql-server

According to documentation, open_transaction_count means, "Number of transactions that are open for this request." It's the '*open for this request*' part that is confusing to me. What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

It mean how many active online transaction you have on that specific database. Select statements wouldn't count.

```
`Use 'yourDB'
GO 

-- Check this first
select db_name(database_id) as DBNAME,open_transaction_count
  from sys.dm_exec_requests
 where session_id = 'yourSPID' 

--Then run the Begin Tran statement below, and check the above select statement again. 

begin tran
go 

rollback --- close with no changes`
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the ones I can think off.

Transactions that are:

- Not committed yet
- Rolling back
- Active connection doing nothing (sleeping)